# "Ciempiés" used colloquially

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

My (old) Spanish dictionary has a 2nd definition of "ciempiés" as "preposterous, disconnected work". Have you ever heard ciempiés used this way in Spanish? It is very funny.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.se]. Thank you. This question made me learn something. In any case, as you can see, it could have been answered by a simple search in the dictionary. Please, check the [ask], [tour] and [help] sections to learn more about the philosophy of this site. Don't hesitate to ask for help if you need it. Welcome again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already saw in your dictionary, "ciempiés" does indeed have this second meaning of "something convoluted, incoherent, preposterous".
I myself didn't know this; I always thought that, in that context, "ciempiés" was only used as an analogy, not in a pure semantical way.

Anyways, *since your question is not about the meaning itself, but actual uses of the word with that meaning*, I looked "ciempiés" up in [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (historical uses, before 1970: 70 results found) and [CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html) (current uses, after 1970: 61 uses found).

**Only 8 out of 131 total appearances of "ciempiés" use that alternative meaning of "preposterous, disconnected work"** -- and one of the most recent, from a newspaper in 1989, even had to explain the meaning so it could be understood by their readers:

> ***Ciempiés: pensamiento o cosa desatinada, confusa o incoherente***, dice el diccionario, después de describir al animal de múltiples patitas, cuyos movimientos son también "inconexos y anárquicos", cita Manuel Trillo, impulsor del Grupo de Autoapoyo de Portadores del VIH y Enfermos de SIDA que lleva este nombre. (...) Este **ciempiés** desatinado acoge a gentes con prácticas homosexuales, hemofílicos, drogodependientes, prostitutas, enfermos e infectados asintomáticos (...)
>   <sub>El País, 01/12/1989 : El ciempiés desatinado</sub>

Some other examples:

> La historia de Ávila es un **ciempiés** a cuya confusión cooperaron con entusiasmo los corregidores Nuño González del Águila y Bernal de Mata, el cronista Gonzalo de Ayora, el benedictino T. Ariz y un sinfín de fabulosos escritores más (...)
>   <sub>Camilo José Cela, *Judíos, moros y cristianos*, 1956.</sub>

---

> Necesito un plano de Roma y ahora estaba intentando ver si podía, de memoria, trazar un croquis. No es tarea fácil, porque Roma, al revés de París, resulta un **ciempiés**. Los herederos de la cultura latina no son ya los italianos. La claridad y el sentido de la medida son ahora cualidades francesas.
>   <sub>Lorenzo Villalonga, *Bearn, o la sala de las muñecas*, 1956.</sub>

---

> (...) pero un pintor que tiene siete u ocho maneras, ¿qué demonio es?, impresionista, cubista, productor de arte negro, dibujante minucioso y académico..., y todo ello al mismo tiempo. Esto está cerca de ser un **ciempiés**. Picasso parece un excéntrico musical que toca varios instrumentos. Se le toma por violinista, y toca el saxófono. Se dice que va a lucirse con la guitarra, y sale con un solo de flauta.
>   <sub>Pío Baroja, *Desde la última vuelta del camino. Memorias*, 1944.</sub>

---

> A Hurtado no le importaba nada la cuestión de los métodos y de las clasificaciones, ni saber si la Sociología era una ciencia o un **ciempiés** inventado por los sabios; lo que quería encontrar era una orientación, una verdad espiritual y práctica al mismo tiempo.
>   <sub>Pío Baroja, *El árbol de la ciencia*, 1911.</sub>

---

> Te diré, pues, que contraviniendo toda ley escrita, la chavala siguió atrayéndome y fascinándome, y sus debilidades manifiestas no me quitaron la ilusión de aquel extraño resplandor moral que creí ver en ella. Esto te parecerá un **ciempiés**; pero como es te lo cuento, y con la realidad no se gastan bromas.
>   <sub>Benito Pérez Galdós, *La incógnita*, 1888.</sub>

---

> La mayor parte de los académicos están a oscuras en materia de filología propiamente dicha; ni han estudiado la ciencia del lenguaje como hay que estudiarla para sacar partido de ella en aplicaciones a la gramática y al léxico del idioma nacional, ni conocen las lenguas sabias ni otras muchas que es necesario conocer para meterse en honduras de lingüística. La Academia viene a ser, en asuntos de diccionario, y especialmente de etimologías, lo que sería un jurado popular conociendo en materia de técnica jurídica: un **ciempiés**.
>   <sub>Clarín (Leopoldo Alas), *Apolo en Pafos*, 1887.</sub>

---

As you can see, uses of "ciempiés" with that meaning are sparse to say the least, the most recent one being from almost 30 years ago, and it doesn't seem to be used at all in common language (journalists wouldn't have to explain it if it wasn't so).
But yeah, it can be used like that and people would kind of understand you, if only by analogy to the small, wriggly creature.

Answer (score 4):

I never heard it used that way, but just by checking the dictionary we see

> [**ciempiés**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9AvIv81)
>
> 2. m. coloq. Obra o trabajo desatinado o incoherente.

So it is a colloquial expression, and indeed it seems to have that (rather obscure) meaning of a "*preposterous, disconnected work*".

Since the "ciempiés" (centipede) happens to be a long, thing and segmented body, with a pair of legs on each segment of the body (21, according to the dictionary's definition) it is easy to understand the similitude between something "disconnected" and the description of such bug.

Answer (score 3):

Forty years ago, there was a freeway off ramp in Caracas, Venezuela that was shown as "El ciempiés" on the road signs.  It was indeed, incredibly convoluted.

I don't know if it's still called that, or not.

Comment: It seems to still be there: [Distribuidor El Ciempiés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuidor_El_Ciempi%C3%A9s)